# Mysqli multiple queries getting info from eachother

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I wish to link two queries to eachother, the first query so I can pull some information needed from the database to do a WHERE for the next query.

Example:

```
  $var2 = $_GET['var2'];
     $fetch = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT owner, price FROM houses WHERE owner = '$var2'" );
                      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch);
                      $fetch1 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Bank FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '$row[owner]'" );
                      $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch1);

             echo $row['owner'];
             echo $row['price'];
             echo $row1['Bank'];
```

For some reason it doesn't output anything. It just gives me a blank page when I put this URL in ?var2=10 (which is linked to a row in the database which is perfectly fine)

I hope anyone can help me. Since I can't figure it out.
I think the error is with this: `WHERE Unique_Id = '$row[owner]'" );`

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing single quete here

Try this

```
$fetch1 = mysqli_query($db_handle, "SELECT Bank FROM playerdata WHERE Unique_Id = '".$row['owner']."'");
```

Read this link [Mysql_identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

and one more thing `mysqli` does not automatically secure your value use `bind` them